# Android custom Soft-Keyboard is not working properly inside the same application.

Tags: keyboard, android-softkeyboard

I have developed an android custom Soft-Keyboard with keys combination with each of key but unfortunately the keys combinations are not working properly inside the application, outside the same application those combinations are working perfectly.
Means when i press any key in android their is a time duration to press some other keys to change the output text/replaces the last output character.

Comment: Question is not clear.you must to give more details about your question.

Comment: Post your code please.